# Check if double of element in first list is present in second list and print the output

Tags: python, list

Suppose

```
List1 = [ 23, 45, 6, 7, 34]
List2 = [46, 23, 1, 14, 68, 56]
```

Compare `List1` and `List2` and  print the element of `List1` which have a double value in `List2`

```
Output = [23,7,34]
```

Comment: How 7 and 34 have duplicate values? I do not see them in `List2`...

Comment: @Johnny, Double, Not duplicate.

Comment: `list(set(x for x in list1 if x * 2 in list2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `list2` to a set for efficient lookups, and use a list comprehension with the said condition for the desired output:

```
set2 = set(List2)
[i for i in List1 if i * 2 in set2]
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
Output = [i for i in List1 if i*2 in List2]
```

Comment: What is the meaning of i for i??

Comment: @PranavSinha it means that for each item in list1. look here for more info:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer but just of the sake of simplicity. Basically you want to iterate through `List1` and check if double value is in `List2`. If so add element to the `output` array.

```
List1 = [ 23, 45, 6, 7, 34]
List2 = [46, 23, 1, 7, 14, 68, 56]

output = []

for i in List1:
    if i*2 in List2:
        output.append(i)

print output
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got the answers. However, just for fun, I came up with the following method. I did not benchmark all the approaches listed here. It can be fun to do that. This is an interesting question and can be investigated more. However, just for the sake of it I present the solution I did.

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array(List1) * 2
print(l)

## array([46, 90, 12, 14, 68])

print(set(l) & set(List2))
## {68, 46, 14}

l2 = set(l) & set(List2)

print([List1[list(np.nonzero(l == i))[0][0]] for i in l if i in l2])
## [23, 7, 34]
```

It uses the broadcasting of numpy along with the fast intersection operation of Python set. This maybe useful if the two lists are very big.